# Concept of Virtual Environments

Tags: linux, virtualenv, virtual

Hope this question belongs here.

As a linux noob, I am sure my question sounds confusing and heavily non-technical, but please help me understand this.

- [Anaconda Python Distribution](http://conda.pydata.org/docs/using/envs.html) comes with the concept of creating environments where I can maintain a variety of `python` versions and specific packages based on my need. Without disturbing other versions and their modules!
- [rbenv](https://github.com/rbenv/rbenv) does the same thing with `ruby`.
- I guess [nvm](https://github.com/creationix/nvm) does it with `nodejs`.
- In fact, the simplest examples are python's `virtualenv` and `virtualenvwrapper`

I need some help or a resource to read and understand how all these things work exactly. Is learning the whole concept of virtualization the only way?

I am sure this has something (everything?) to do with the OS, esp. Linux. To make these things clearer in my head, the best is to try things at the OS level. Is there a resource where I can find such help/tutorial/etc.?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might find these links useful.

[realpython.com](https://realpython.com/blog/python/python-virtual-environments-a-primer/)
[dabapps.com](https://www.dabapps.com/blog/introduction-to-pip-and-virtualenv-python/)

Comment: Thanks a lot. Looks like it really has a lot of details. Once it makes sense in case of python, generalizing should be reasonably easier. Thanks.